# Accessing layer contents in Android-surfaceflinger

Tags: android, android-source, surfaceflinger

I am reading the **layer** contents to check whether its the same content as that rendered by the app on-screen. I am reading the contents before they are being composited by **SurfaceFlinger**. Here is the block of code in **HWCLayerVersion1**::**setAcquireFenceFd**() in **HWComposer.cpp**, to dump the layer content/**pixels** to a raw-file.

```
    getLayer()->acquireFenceFd = fenceFd;
    private_handle_t *hnd = (private_handle_t*)getLayer()->handle; // the handle of the layer

    /*code for checking layer contents*/
    if(private_handle_t::validate(getLayer()->handle)==0){
             ALOGD("beta: we are gonna read a valid buffer-> %08x", intptr_t(getLayer()->handle));
             char filename[64];
             memset(filename, 0, 64);
             int name = clock();
             sprintf(filename, "/data/dump.%08x.raw", intptr_t(getLayer()->handle));                
             if(getLayer()->acquireFenceFd >= 0){
                  int ret = sync_wait(getLayer()->acquireFenceFd, -1);
                  if(ret < 0){
                        ALOGD("beta: sync_wait failed");
                  } else{
                      FILE *file = fopen(filename,"w+");
                      //ALOGD("beta: writing pixels");
                      fwrite((void*)hnd->base, hnd->size, 1, file);
                      close(getLayer()->acquireFenceFd);
                      //getLayer()->acquireFenceFd = -1;
                  } 
              } else {
                   ALOGD("beta: fencefd not valid");
              }
    }
```

When I am reading the pixels using **IrfanView** with the appropriate attributes, the image only faintly resembles the actual content, but the colors are all smudged. What is the reason behind this? Is the buffer being rendered while I am reading the content? I'm totally new to AOSP, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "colors are all smudged"?  Can you post good/bad sample images? (you'll probably need to do that on an external site and post a link -- I think you need higher rep to include them inline)  What device are you testing on?

Comment: I'm so very sorry for posting this question. A few minutes after posting this, I tried a new resolution, and everything works! turns out I was not using the correct resolution in IrfanView. Wasted a whole day for no reason at all! One question though, is it necessary that I wait on the acquireFenceFd, because it seems to be working without it too?

Answer (score 0):

If your host (in case its an emulator) or device supports graphic acceleration , then yes, the buffer you are reading is not fully rendered yet.
Latest Android releases support a sync mechanism which means that buffers (layers) can be acquired by the SurfaceFlinger while they are being rendered. They are protected by a fencing mechanism which ensures that a buffer that's not fully rendered will not be displayed.

Comment: But sync_wait() should wait till the buffer is fully rendered, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: if you can help would you help please about that problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705858/intent-does-not-work