# Intent does not work

Tags: android

On clicking the order app in the app that i have created, it calls the submitOrder() method and it is supposed to display the order summary by calling the createOrderSummary() method in gmail .However the gmail app does not open and it displays the message (which is in the else block )that I can’t display the intent.(i am new to android development.)

```
CheckBox whippedCreamBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_check_box);
boolean isWhippedCreamBoxChecked = whippedCreamBox.isChecked();
CheckBox chocolateBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chocalate_check_box);
boolean isChocolateBoxChecked = chocolateBox.isChecked();
int price = calculatePrice(quantity, isWhippedCreamBoxChecked, isChocolateBoxChecked);
EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
Editable userEnteredString = nameEditText.getText();
String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(userEnteredString, price, isWhippedCreamBoxChecked, isChocolateBoxChecked);
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:ritvikupadhyay2000@gmail.com"));
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(sendIntent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Order for the just java app");
sendIntent.putExtra(sendIntent.EXTRA_TEXT, priceMessage);

if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
else
{
    displayMessage("I can't display the intent");
}
```

and here is the java code for createOrderSummary()

```
private String createOrderSummary(Editable userEnteredString, int price, boolean isWhippedCreamBoxChecked, boolean isChocalateBoxChecked) {

String priceMessage = "Name:" + userEnteredString + "\nAdd whipped cream?" + isWhippedCreamBoxChecked + "\nAdd chocalate?" + isChocalateBoxChecked + "\nQuantity:" + quantity + "\nTotal:$" + price + "\nThank you!\n";
return priceMessage;
```

Comment: what is the error in your logcat

Comment: There is no error apart from          06-05 23:20:10.049 20950-20950/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Unable to create /sdcard/ramdump,

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it is from official docs.
And also note to use String array, many claims using `String array` only works.

```
  public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Following the above code snippet but if i remove this statement sendIntent.setType("text/plain"); , then it asks what i want to use. why?

Comment: It will ask you to choose a mail app you prefer if you have multiple mailing apps.

Comment: What i meant was that with  sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
The disambiguation dialogue does not pop up , whereas if remove the above statement then it appears. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea :)

Comment: No problem. anyway Thanks